# How do I share some session variables across Django Subdomain sessions

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that has wildcard subdomains. The user has multiple login sessions across these subdomains. For example, he goes to sd1.site.com and logs in(HTTP POST request to sd1.site.com/login/)  with credentials username1 and password1. This creates a session for the user on sd1.site.com. He then goes to sd2.site.com and logs in with credentials username2 and password2. This creates a session for the user on sd2.site.com.

My end goal is to tell sd1.site.com that the user is logged in from sd2.site.com as well. My plan is to store a session variable called 'domains_logged_in' with value ['sd1','sd2']. Both sd1 and sd2 should be able to access 'domains_logged_in'.

Setting SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.site.com' is not an option as it makes it difficult to manage multiple sessions and is not entirely secure. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are persisting your sessions. If you are using cookies to persist your sessions which seems likely, and you aren't willing to use a `.site.com` cookie domain, then you need to offload your session storage to something like Redis or some other key/store sort of server agnostic option.